# xrdp - login failed

Tags: xrdp

I m running xrdp on my debian server. When I try to log in I get the error xrdp_mm_processes_login:login failed. I removed the package and re-installed but still the same. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds familiary to a problem we had.  Fixing it required installing the 32-bit version of `polkit`.